# skin color segmentation using YCbCr colorspace

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, image-processing, dimensions

I am trying to execute this code but I am getting the below stated error. It says that the array size doesn't match. I have tried a few solutions given on the internet. Changed the values of the color and also tried by removing the np.array from the code in the concerned lines

```
 skin_ycrcb_min = np.array((0, 138, 67)) 
 skin_ycrcb_max = np.array((255, 173, 133))
```

Bellow is the code:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import util as ut
import svm_train as st 
import re
model=st.trainSVM(17)
#create and train SVM model each time coz bug in opencv 3.1.0 svm.load() 
https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/issues/4969
cam=int(raw_input("Enter Camera number: "))
cap=cv2.VideoCapture(cam)
font = cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX

def nothing(x) :
pass

text= " "

temp=0
previouslabel=None
previousText=" "
label = None
while(cap.isOpened()):
_,img=cap.read()
cv2.rectangle(img,(900,100),(1300,500),(255,0,0),3) # bounding box which 
captures ASL sign to be detected by the system
img1=img[100:500,900:1300]
img_ycrcb = cv2.cvtColor(img1, cv2.COLOR_BGR2YCR_CB)
blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(img_ycrcb,(11,11),0)
skin_ycrcb_min = np.array((0, 138, 67))
skin_ycrcb_max = np.array((255, 173, 133))
mask = cv2.inRange(blur, skin_ycrcb_min, skin_ycrcb_max);  # detecting the 
hand in the bounding box using skin detection
contours,hierarchy = cv2.findContours(mask.copy(),cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, 2) 
cnt=ut.getMaxContour(contours,4000)                       # using contours 
to capture the skin filtered image of the hand
if cnt!=None:
    gesture,label=ut.getGestureImg(cnt,img1,mask,model)   # passing the 
trained model for prediction and fetching the result
    if(label!=None):
        if(temp==0):
            previouslabel=label
        if previouslabel==label :
            previouslabel=label
            temp+=1
        else :
            temp=0
        if(temp==40):
            if(label=='P'):

                label=" "
            text= text + label
            if(label=='Q'):
                words = re.split(" +",text)
                words.pop()
                text = " ".join(words)
                #text=previousText
            print text

    cv2.imshow('PredictedGesture',gesture)                # showing the best 
match or prediction
    cv2.putText(img,label,(50,150), font,8,(0,125,155),2)  # displaying the 
predicted letter on the main screen
    cv2.putText(img,text,(50,450), font,3,(0,0,255),2)
cv2.imshow('Frame',img)
cv2.imshow('Mask',mask)
k = 0xFF & cv2.waitKey(10)
if k == 27:
    break
cap.release()        
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "C:\Users\hlllv\Desktop\ASL\ASL-Translator-master\ASL.py", line 29, in 
<module>
 mask = cv2.inRange(blur, skin_ycrcb_min, skin_ycrcb_max);  # detecting the 
hand in the bounding box using skin detection
error: C:\build\2_4_winpack-bindings-win32-vc14- 
static\opencv\modules\core\src\arithm.cpp:2711: error: (-209) The lower 
bounary is neither an array of the same size and same type as src, nor a 
scalar in function cv::inRange
```

Please help!

Comment: tuples are not the same as lists!! this line `skin_ycrcb_min = np.array((0, 138, 67))` should be `skin_ycrcb_min = np.array([0, 138, 67])` ... same thing with the line after it

Comment: I tried what you asked, but its still showing the same error.

Comment: Print the number of channels using `print blur.shape`, before your `cv2.inRange()` method, to see the number of channels in `blur` matrix. The error log is saying that `blur` matrix is not a 3-channel matrix.